# How do I get top left position of wrapped content?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to identify the top left corner of an HTML node so that I can have an arrow point to that spot. However, when the content of the node wraps, this gets tricky because the box defined by the node's top, left, bottom, and right attributes does not match the actual node anymore.  As an example, here is sample HTML and a JSFiddle below and I want to get the exact position of the first word in the highlighted sentence:

```
<div class="container">
This is the first sentence. <span id="highlight">This is the second sentence, but it is so long, that it wraps to the next line, making it's starting point hard to identify.</span>  This is the last sentence and it doesn't matter.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2cf1oe7/

I feel like it should be simple, but, thus far, I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

span is a inline element so in general it does not have offset and position like top, left, width....

[See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

In this case you need to add a span beside the `#highlight`

```js
var v=document.getElementById('highlight').offsetLeft;
document.getElementById('mark').style.left=v+'px';
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
}

#highlight {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#mark{
  width:3px;
  height:3px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="mark"></div>
<span>This is the first sentence.</span><span id="highlight">This is the second sentence, but it is so long, that it wraps to the next line.</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `#mark` now is at the top left of `#highlight`